# Bad audit on first post "Adding spaces to string based on list"

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I just failed an audit with the post https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/23274370 as "This was a high quality post and you should have considered leaving it as-is or even upvoting." and I tried to comment with "what did you try?"
I completely disagree with the "high quality" and just voted that post down, but also want it killed from the audits: the question is clear, but there is no code provided and we're not on stackoverflow to write code for users!
Don't you all agree? Who can kill that audit?
EDIT: the original question itself is at [Adding spaces to string based on list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56305553/adding-spaces-to-string-based-on-list)

Comment: [Became Hot Network Question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56305553/revisions)

Comment: I hate to jump on the meta effect train, but "gimme code" is neither a good question nor a good audit.

Comment: *we're not on stackoverflow to write code for users!* ... well, yes we are. We write code all the time for users. Most answers being posted have code. How can I do *foo* is a valid question and is on-topic despite popular belief. If you think the question is useful for future visitors and well researched, an upvote is warranted. If you think the question isn't useful without code cast a down vote. Questions don't become bad only due to no attempt of the OP.

Comment: It may be interesting to keep the question, especially as it has several nice answers, if there is a way to prevent it from being used as an audit next...

Comment: And by "write code", I was mostly thinking about all those "do my homework" questions without any attempt done and the full code to give away... Of course most answers must also contain (fixed) code!

Comment: Bad audits appear all the time- whether they're mentioned on meta or not. I've mostly given up on reviewing queues in SO because I either skip the majority of questions or spend time over-analyzing a post that results in a review audit failure.

Comment: Looks like a good audit to me.

Comment: @chevybow Usually when I begin to over-analyze the post I notice the "answers: 0; accepted: yes" :)