# Audit question feedback / flagging / vetting / stats?

Tags: feature-request, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I just got my first ban for failing too many audits.

The problem is that I disagree with most of these failed audits (but you can skip this paragraph):

On [Bad audit on first post "Adding spaces to string based on list"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386083/bad-audit-on-first-post-adding-spaces-to-string-based-on-list) I discussed a question that was then voted +12 or +13, while not showing any code nor attempt to do some.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/23317568 is an answer that was deleted as being a link only, but is actually quite interesting / makes senses.

I failed https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/23236168 when I got it as triage, because I said it requires editing: the question is quite interesting for me, but there are the 2 dead links to remove. But I was supposed to reject it fully...

Anyway, as there are already tons of questions on meta about bad audit questions, I don't want to discuss more about specific examples, but I want ways to fix these audits.

The first idea would be to have an option to "comment" on the audit questions, especially when we failed but likely even when we "passed": it would be much easier to directly give feedback after the audit than creating one more meta debate. Either my leaving a comment/feedback, or by a new flagging system, showing that the audit was already said to be bad (or good!) N times, and automatically rejecting them after a threshold.

Another idea would be to make sure the audits are vetted by "power users" as being OK or not (and clear enough for an audit, not just borderline?), before being used on us. Or just tested on us without any consequences, just to get statistics: if, say, an audit question failed 75% of the time, maybe, just maybe, it might be because of the question rather than because of us reviewers!?

And talking about stats, I hope data are already being collected about the failure rate per audit question!? And acted upon? That would be the minimum, as even if it wouldn't end our ban after the fact, it may prevent other reviewer from getting banned again because of them...

Comment: Those audits aren't broken.  They did their job well, you did indeed fail them.

Comment: How-to questions do not require an attempt to solve the problem, or code at all. They must be on-topic, well-defined (unambiguous, not open to interpretation), and reasonably scoped (asking how to do one thing, not seven).  Only debugging questions explicitly require code.

Comment: The second one linked seems to (possibly) be spam, fwiw. The first one is clear as day NAA, though.

Comment: @jhpratt - "there is Flex Layout which will wrap items." (https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/23317568) is definitely an answer (so not NAA), I'd even say it is not link-only answer as it gives you component name... granted not very good (and I have no idea of correctness) answer - but I can see how it is questionable audit.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov That's the First Posts queue, though. OP definitely should have done something other than "No Action Needed" even if they didn't flag it.

Comment: Second one isn't spam, as it links to official docs. All three are superior audits, which is surprising. Please, stop reviewing things until you have a better understanding of what's acceptable.

Answer (score 5):

> ...and automatically rejecting them after a threshold.

A lot of people failing an audit doesn't necessarily mean it's bad. It could just mean it's doing its job of slowing down reviewers who aren't paying attention.

> Another idea would be to make sure the audits are vetted by "power users" as being OK or not...

Aside from needing high reputation users to be willing to work another queue, it would mean that what gets chosen as an audit is determined by a few users instead of genuinely reflecting the opinions of the community as a whole.

More importantly, you'd need to show that it's a big enough problem to be worth the work. Right now meta discussions seem to work for either getting bad audits dealt with or explaining why it's a good audit to the person who failed it.

Why do we need something other than meta to handle this?